# Modifying & Duplicating File Object in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a component in React where I pass it a file object. I do various things with this File object, but I am also adding new values to the File object by doing `this.props.file.color = #000`

Within my component, I have a function that triggers a parent function to duplicate the File Object

**Component**

```
duplicate =()=> {
    this.props.file.color = this.getColor();
    console.log(this.props.file)
    //File Object
    // -- color: #cb0000
    // -- name:filename.png
    this.props.duplicate(this.props.file);
}
```

As you can see, it has added a color value to the File Object, and the filename is correct. I then pass this data back to a duplication function in my parent

**Parent**

i is the array  index, a is the File Object

```
  duplicate(i, a) {
    let dupeArr = a;
    const arr = [...this.state.files];

    const index = i + 1;
    let name = dupeArr.name.slice(0, -4);
    Object.defineProperty(dupeArr, 'name', { writeable: true, value: `${name}-${a.color}.png`})

    arr.splice(index, 0, a);
    console.log(arr)
    // 2x File Objects
    // Original file
    // -- #cb0000 (Correct)
    // -- filename-#cb0000.png (Incorrect, why is it changing this name?)
    //Duplicated file
    // -- -- #cb0000 (Correct)
    // -- filename-#cb0000.png (Correct)
    this.setState({
      files: arr
    })
  }
```

What I am doing here is taking the File Object that was passed to it, defining the name of that File Object and then splicing into the existing files array before setting it as state.

For some reason though, when I define the name property, it is changing the name in both the original entry in the array, as well as my new File Object.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when the files were uploaded, the were File Objects and it is not possible to copy a File Object.

The easy solution was to take @deowk's duplication solution, but also to convert the File Objects to a JSON Object on upload, only taking what I needed:

```
  onDrop(files) {
    let f = files.map(file => ({
      name: file.name,
      preview: file.preview
    }));

        this.setState({
            files: this.state.files.length > 0 ? [...this.state.files, ...f] : f,
        });
  }
```

Comment: Glad you sorted it out...;)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are mutating the original file object, and it is still being referenced in `this.state.files`. You are making a copy of your files array here:

```js
const arr = [...this.state.files];
```

But this does not in fact produce copies of the file objects contained in the array. They are still referencing the original objects.

You are running into issues because you are mutating the file object at this line and your copied array is still referencing the original object:

```js
Object.defineProperty(dupeArr, 'name', { writeable: true, value: `${name}-${a.color}.png`})
```

Assuming you are converting the File object to a normal JS Object (like you mentioned in your answer) and then only passing the index of the object you want to modify to `duplicate`:

```js
duplicate = (index) => {
  let filesCopy = [...this.state.files];
  let objToModify = filesCopy[index];
  let objModified = {...objToModify, name: /* somename */, preview: /* some preview */ }

  filesCopy.push(objToModify);

  this.setState({ files: filesCopy });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem this causes though is that my duplicated content stays as a File Object, but the original File Object, now just becomes a plain object and looses some of its values. For example `
File(669110) {preview: "blob", processedSrc: "base64", name: "APRIL2018-D23-LVL13.png", lastModified: 1524493156000, …}` becomes `{preview: "blob", processedSrc: "base64", color: "hex"}

Comment: Ah ok I see, I have edited my answer with a possible solution, just create a new copy of the file inside map if it's the one you want to 'update'

Comment: I've just tried to reduce a load of my code before I saw your edit, and again I am running into the mutation issue.  Essentially now, I just pass the duplicate function the index of the object I want to copy. How would I go about duplicating the object and editing it without mutation?

Comment: I have edited my answer, you can change the `let objModified = ....` line depending on the fields you want to change, It's also based of the assumption that you are using a normal JS Object vs File Object. Let me know if thats correct otherwise I can modify it to work with a File Object